# Displaying Query Results in Microsoft Access with no VB

Tags: ms-access-2016

I would like to run a query using a macro and display the results in a message box. The aim is to be  able to pass the value as a parameter to another form in the database. First I want to be able to see the value returned from the query. I would then like to set a temp variable to this value so I can pass it as a parameter.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to add a DCount inside the message box which didn't work. I tried to set a local variable but i'm not sure how to get the query to run. I did the same with temp variable but had the same issue. I'm trying not to use VB.